# Open Facebook Post in Facebook App From iPhone App

Tags: xcode, facebook, url-scheme

If I have the id of a Facebook post, how can I open it in the native Facebook app? I am able to open links using [UIApplication sharedApplication] but I cannot come up with the correct URL scheme. For instance, fb://profile/pidhere works to open the profile but I can't figure out how to open an individual post. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been asked many times here. And the answer is: it's not possible.

There are methods to do this on Android, but that is not officially supported. You should not rely on it. This is the same for iOS. Some links work, but they are unsupported, can change any time and for some items, such as posts, it's not possible at all.